# 5V sensor to Raspberry PI

Tags: input-device

If I have a sensor which has 5V ouptut:

1. I can't plug it directly to Raspberry PI, right?
2. If so, what would I need to do so I would be able to do so?

I would like to connect it via input pins.

Comment: Also, I'd suggest some [googling](http://www.google.com/search?q=raspberry%20pi%205v%20sensor) as I see many answers to this already.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use two or three resistors to form a voltage divider

```
Input----[ 1k ]-----[ 2k ]---GND
                 |
                 |
                 |
               GPIO PIN
```

If your wires aren't too long, you can use higher resistors - say 10k & 20k

If you can't find 2k resistor, you can connect 2 1k resistors in series

```
Input----[ 1k ]-----[ 1k ]-----[ 1k ]---GND
                 |
                 |
                 |
               GPIO PIN
```

Comment: Can you also use a logic level shifter?

Comment: @SteveRobillard, that would be another way. You could also use an optoisolater if the output of the sensor can source/sink enough current.

Comment: Might I suggest you expand your answer to include those for completeness. Maybe including links to http://www.adafruit.com/products/757 and http://www.adafruit.com/products/395 Assuming you do I will delete my conmments.

Comment: I'm curious about when to use 1k/2k resistors versus using 10k/20k. I know that thanks to Ohms law, V=IR, therefore using higher value resistors will lower the current.  Is the idea to use sufficient resistance to lower the current to the lowest acceptable range to minimize power consumption?

Comment: @HeatfanJohn, There is a compromise between the current and noise immunity. Without knowing anything about the sensor's output impedance, the frequency or the length of wires, 1k/2k resistors is a reasonable starting point.

Comment: 1K + 2K will combine to 3K, which will result in only 1.6mA of current at 5Volt input. You won't be saving any trees by lowering it even more :-)

Comment: How long is "too long"? At what length is it appropriate to use higher valued resistors?

Answer (score 1):

It is correct that you cannot directly connect a 5V sensor to the Raspberry Pi as it provides 3.3V. There's a great new cape for the Pi on kickstarter that allows you to use 5V sensors using GVS connections.
Here's a link: https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1546666383/gvs-board-for-raspberry-pi?ref=discovery

This is a great alternative to painful wiring.